# How to make SVG clip-path work correctly in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, clip-path

I'm using an inline SVG together with CSS `clip-path` property to create a beveled corner on a `div` element.

On Firefox, the size of the beveled corner is correct. However, on Google Chrome, not only the size of the beveled corner is incorrectly smaller, but the size of the `div` element also become incorrectly smaller.

[Here is the demo on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p3qywad/).

How do I make Google Chrome works correctly with SVG and `clip-path`?

P.S. I know CSS generated content can simulate the beveled corner effect. But in my case, I have to use SVG and `clip-path`.

Comment: I have a solution that works in chrome https://jsfiddle.net/2p3qywad/1/.
This does not work in firefox.

Comment: @SamDawson Thanks. I know that pure CSS method. But I need the beveled corner to work on both Firefox and Chrome, and I'm trying to use the shortest code.

Comment: In chrome it looks the square is around 10px smaller on the right and the bottom. Im unsure why.

Comment: It looks like Webkit browsers aren't supporting the feature correctly. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873989/how-to-apply-svg-clippath-to-html-element-that-is-not-in-the-top-left-corner-of).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had found the solution in [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/creating-responsive-shapes-with-clip-path/). The solution is adding `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` to the `clipPath` element, and then change the value of the `points` attribute of the `polygon` element to percentage value.

[Here is the updated demo on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IanY/2p3qywad/2/).

The previous problem was that Google Chrome incorrectly applies the clipping path to the document instead of the HTML element that references it. According to the aforementioned article, setting the value of the `clipPathUnits` attribute to `objectBoundingBox` makes the clipping path honors the boundaries of the HTML element that references it.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that helped me solve this was adding a unique clip-path ID. This, along with the vendor prefix for webkit, helped me get everything working!

```
Example:

<svg>
     (...normal svg stuff...)

     <clipPath id="uniqueId" transform="translate(-0.01)">
       <rect width="90.96" height="78" style="fill: none"/>
     </clipPath>

     ...other svg stuff...

     <g style="clip-path: url(#uniqueId); -webkit-clip-path: url(#uniqueId);">

 </svg>
```

This was for multiple inline svgs and there must have been collision with the Adobe Illustrator-generated "clip-path" ID that the clipPath was given.